# Matplotlib graph not being constrained as expected in frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, customtkinter

As the root window resizes, the figure embedded into the frame will grow and shrink unproportionally and allows parts of the figure to be "cut-off" (i.e. the window edge moves past the bounds of the figure). Is there a way for the figure to hold its proportions/boundaries better?

```
import CTkGraph
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='u')
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform='u')
    graph = CTkGraph.CTkGraph(root)
    graph.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    root.mainloop()
```

Graph Class

```
import tkinter as tk
import customtkinter as ctk

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.ticker import StrMethodFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class CTkGraph(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        allowed_keys = ['dataframe', 'xlabel', 'colors']
        x = np.arange(0, 3, .01)
        y = 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
        self.dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
        self.xlabel = 'x'
        self.ylabel = 'y'
        self.default_color = 'black'
        self.colors = {}

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if key in allowed_keys:
                setattr(self, key, value)

        for column in self.dataframe.columns:
            if column != self.xlabel:
                self.colors.setdefault(column, self.default_color)

        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(layout='tight')

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.plot()



    def plot(self):
        self.ax.cla()
        self.ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(StrMethodFormatter('{x:,.1f}'))
        self.ax.set_xlabel(self.xlabel)
        self.ax.set_ylabel(self.ylabel)

        for column in self.dataframe.columns:
            if column != self.xlabel:
                self.ax.plot(self.dataframe[self.xlabel], self.dataframe[column], self.colors[column], linewidth=1)

        self.fig.tight_layout()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Normal View:
[image: normal view]

Unwanted Behavior (x axis label is being cut off):
[image: unwanted behavior]

Comment: See [How to set tight_layout for matplotlib graphs after show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968489/how-to-set-tight-layout-for-matplotlib-graphs-after-show) about calling an event handler to reapply `tight_layout` after resizing.

Comment: Adding self.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.fig.tight_layout()) to the constructor seems to correctly apply the tight_layout when the window is resized.  However, this doesnt seem to apply when the widget is added via grid (e.g. if the root windows size is set to 800x200, the x-axis is cutoff until the window is resized).

I would assume the Configure event would trigger given the description, but that does not seem to be the case and I'm not seeing another event that would be applicable. Any ideas?

Comment: Changing the bind function to: self.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.fig.set(layout_engine='constrained')) seems to be working for me